# Prints to the serial monitor are being overwritten

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, esp32

Using esp32, Arduino IDE 1.8.9 on OSX.

My code is interspersed with `Serial.println()` writes to the serial monitor of various status messages.

As far as I can tell, if a `println` is not fully written out to the serial monitor before another `println` is sent, then the first `println` does not finish displaying properly, and appears to garbled.

I'm using baud rate 115200.

I'm guessing that there's no flow control between the serial monitor and the computer.

It's strange though because I've been doing quite a bit of Arduino IDE programming for a while now but I don't ever recall this being an issue.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be going on, and how I can ensure that messages are fully displayed on the serial monitor?

Comment: I've never had such an issue - perhaps you're doing something *unusual* in your code - are you able to create a minimal piece of code that produces this odd behaviour

Comment: There is no flow control. Please post code that exhibits this behaviour - perhaps you have a bug.